# Creating comma-separated list of paths (allowing for spaces in path), and passing result as a variable to use again

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to use output from rtcontrol (Part of [Pyroscope](https://github.com/pyroscope/pyrocore)) which is used to control [rtorrent](https://rakshasa.github.io/rtorrent/) tfrom the command line. I am having issues formatting the output from one call to use as input to another

I'd like to be able to only choose the torrents that satisfy that criteria but DO NOT share a path with another torrent.

The process is as follows

```
PATHS=$(rtcontrol ratio=+2 completed=+5d -qopath)

echo $PATHS
# Output
# /home/user/path/name1
# /home/user/path/name2
# /home/user/path/name 3
# /home/user/path/name 3
# /home/user/path/name 4
# /home/user/path/name5

# Remove duplicates paths and convert $PATHS to comma delimited variable PATHS.
#
# UNSURE HERE....
#
# PATHS="/home/user/path/name1","/home/user/path/name2","/home/user/path/name 3","/home/user/path/name 4","/home/user/path/name5"

#Pass PATHS to rtcontrol again to get torrents in one of the paths.
PATHS_2=$(rtcontrol path=$PATHS -qopath)

echo $PATHS_2
#output
#/home/user/path/name1
#/home/user/path/name1
#/home/user/path/name2
#/home/user/path/name 3
#/home/user/path/name 3
#/home/user/path/name 4
#/home/user/path/name5

# Remove duplicates and convert $PATHS_2 to comma delimited variable.
#
# UNSURE HERE....
#
# PATHS_2="/home/user/path/name2","/home/user/path/name 3","/home/user/path/name 4","/home/user/path/name5"

#Pass to rtcontrol to perform action
rtcontrol path=$PATHS_2 --cull
```

The reason for this is it is possible that a torrent DOES NOT satisfy the conditions or `ratio=+2 completed=+5d`, but has the same path as one that DOES. This is the reason for the second call `rtcontrol path=$PATHS -qopath`

I have tried different combinations of `uniq, sed and awk` as well as using pipes to pass along output. It should be noted that `rtcontrol` output can be piped out e.g. `rtcontrol name="*Test* -qoname|uniq -u`

This can be handled in pure bash, or with Python. There are also python libraries to interface with the torrent program that can perform similar functions, and even more advanced things that I am investigating.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/bin/python
 import os
 import sys

 paths = {}
 for line in sys.stdin:
   path = line.strip()
   paths[path] = path
 print ','.join( sorted( paths.keys() )
 exit( 0 )
```